# Uncaught TypeError: createProfile is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Uncaught TypeError: createProfile is not a function
    at onSubmit (CreateProfile.js:47:1)
    at onSubmit (CreateProfile.js:58:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
```

I am getting this error, and i am not able to figure out why. I am trying to call the createProfile function so i can make a post request to the database and also change the State. After clicking the submit button, GET_PROFILE action must occur. But this error keeps showing up. I tried to console.log in the function, turns out, the function is not being run at all.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setAlert } from "./alert";

import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR } from "./types";

// Get current users profile

export const getCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/profile/me");

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
    });
  }
};

// Create or update profile
export const createProfile =
  (formData, navigate, edit = false) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    //  await console.log("run hua");
    try {
      // console.log("try");
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      const res = await axios.post("/profile", formData, config);

      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data,
      });

      dispatch(setAlert(edit ? "Profile Updated" : "Profile Created"));

      if (!edit) {
        navigate("/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      const errors = err.response.data.errors;

      if (errors) {
        errors.forEach((error) => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
      }

      dispatch({
        type: PROFILE_ERROR,
        payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status },
      });
    }
  };
```

This is the createProfile function

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";

import { withRouter} from "../routing/WithRouter";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createProfile} from "../../actions/profile";



const CreateProfile = (createProfile, navigate) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    company: "",
    website: "",
    location: "",
    status: "",
    skills: "",
    githubusername: "",
    bio: "",
    twitter: "",
    facebook: "",
    linkedin: "",
    youtube: "",
    instagram: "",
  });
  const [displaySocialInputs, toggleSocialinputs] = useState(false);

  const {
    company,
    website,
    location,
    status,
    skills,
    githubusername,
    bio,
    twitter,
    facebook,
    linkedin,
    youtube,
    instagram,
  } = formData;

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {  
      e.preventDefault();
      createProfile(formData, navigate);

  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="large text-primary">Create Your Profile</h1>
      <p className="lead">
        <i className="fas fa-user"></i> Let's get some information to make your
        profile stand out
      </p>
      <small>* = required field</small>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={e=> onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <select name="status" value={status} onChange={e => onChange(e)}>
            <option value="0">* Select Professional Status</option>
            <option value="Developer">Developer</option>
            <option value="Junior Developer">Junior Developer</option>
            <option value="Senior Developer">Senior Developer</option>
            <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="Student or Learning">Student or Learning</option>
            <option value="Instructor">Instructor or Teacher</option>
            <option value="Intern">Intern</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
          <small className="form-text">
            Give us an idea of where you are at in your career
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Company"
            name="company"
            value={company}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className="form-text">
            Could be your own company or one you work for
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Website"
            name="website"
            value={website}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className="form-text">
            Could be your own or a company website
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Location"
            name="location"
            value={location}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className="form-text">
            City & state suggested (eg. Boston, MA)
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="* Skills"
            name="skills"
            value={skills}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className="form-text">
            Please use comma separated values (eg. HTML,CSS,JavaScript,PHP)
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Github Username"
            name="githubusername"
            value={githubusername}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          />
          <small className="form-text">
            If you want your latest repos and a Github link, include your
            username
          </small>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <textarea
            placeholder="A short bio of yourself"
            name="bio"
            value={bio}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
          ></textarea>
          <small className="form-text">Tell us a little about yourself</small>
        </div>

        <div className="my-2">
          <button
            onClick={() => toggleSocialinputs(!displaySocialInputs)}
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-light"
          >
            Add Social Network Links
          </button>
          <span>Optional</span>
        </div>

        {displaySocialInputs && (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="form-group social-input">
              <i className="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Twitter URL" name="twitter" value={twitter} onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group social-input">
              <i className="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Facebook URL" name="facebook" value={facebook} onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group social-input">
              <i className="fab fa-youtube fa-2x"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="YouTube URL" name="youtube" value={youtube} onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group social-input">
              <i className="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Linkedin URL" name="linkedin" value={linkedin} onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group social-input">
              <i className="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Instagram URL" name="instagram" value={instagram} onChange={e=>onChange(e)}/>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        )}

        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-1" />
        <a className="btn btn-light my-1" href="dashboard.html">
          Go Back
        </a>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

CreateProfile.propTypes = {
    createProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    
};



export default connect(null,{ createProfile })(withRouter(CreateProfile));
```

I called createProfile using onSubmit().
Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the import found the function? Did you log it and see what it is?

Comment: `createProfile` is an argument to `CreateProfile`, but it's not being destructured from `props`.

Comment: When i logged it directly i got something like this {Navigate: ƒ, createProfile: ƒ} in output.

Comment: yes destructuring helped to remove that error